# Is there some way to adding a link (contain php) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I just can't input my link + php code in javascript. pls help me

i dont know why im a beginner

i just want to add this link ===

```
detail.php?id=<?php echo $perproduct["id_product"]; ?>
```

to "HERE~" pls look at the img href ===

```
$output .= '
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
            <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px; height:450px;">
                <img src="photo_product/'. $row['photo_product'] .'" alt="" class="img-responsive" >
                <p align="center"><strong><a href="HERE~">'. $row['name_product'] .'</a></strong></p>
                <h4 style="text-align:center;" class="text-danger" >'. $row['price_product'] .'</h4>
                <p>Camera : '. $row['camera_product'].' MP<br />
                Brand : '. $row['brand_product'] .' <br />
                RAM : '. $row['ram_product'] .' GB<br />
                Storage : '. $row['storage_product'] .' GB </p>
            <div class="add"> <br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Pre-Order</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        ';
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember that php is server-side and Javascript is client-side. By the time your Javascript is activated, the php has done its work and has delivered its generated html to the client. If you want Javascript to run php on demand, you will need to use Ajax. Otherwise, have another think about your application design and the order in which stuff happens. Also, please only tag the question with relevant tags - I can't see what [mysql] is doing in there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```php
$output .= '... <a href="detail.php?id='. $perproduct["id_product"] .'"> ...';
```

Comment: @ElisaChaCha If this works for you, consider accepting this answer.